# How to handle exceptions in HTTPHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, http

I have mail sending program using HTML and asp.net HTTP Handler.

Here is my html page which sends request to .ashx page

```
<html>
<form id="ContactForm" action="EmailHandler.ashx" method="post">
    Name: <input class="input" type="text" id="contactname" name="contactname" autocomplete="on" required/>
    Email <input class="input" type="email" id="contactemail" name="contactemail" autocomplete="on" required />
    Comments<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="contactmessage" name="contactmessage" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="emailsubmit" name="emailsubmit" value="Send" />
</form>
</html>
```

here is my httphandler (EmailHandler.ashx)

```
public class EmailHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        string name = context.Request.Form["contactname"];
        string email = context.Request.Form["contactemail"];
        string content = context.Request.Form["contactmessage"];
        try
        {
            SendEmail(name, email, content);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           *******
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void SendEmail(string name, string emailid, string emailcontent)
    {
        SmtpClient serverobj = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage msgobj = new MailMessage();

        msgobj.To.Add("abc@ymail.com");
        msgobj.Subject = "Its From Guest";
        msgobj.Body = emailcontent;
        msgobj.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msgobj.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        serverobj.Send(msgobj);

    }
```

Now how to handle response from this handler.

1. If email is sent successfully how to reflect the success message to the same html page?
2. If any exception arises how to handle the exception or exception message?

Comment: Look through the HttpContext class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) and see if there aren't any useful places to put your notification/error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `context` to write values directly back to the calling page, like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    string name = context.Request.Form["contactname"];
    string email = context.Request.Form["contactemail"];
    string content = context.Request.Form["contactmessage"];
    try
    {
        SendEmail(name, email, content);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Write exception message to user
       // You can include some of the exception detail via the ex object, 
       // but be careful how much information you divulge to the user 
       context.Response.Write("There was a problem sending the email.");
    }

    // Email was sent successfully
    context.Response.Write("Email sent successfully.");
}
```

Comment: It is printing the result in .ashx page only. I am trying to bring the response to the same html page or to an another html page

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a quite old question, but it still sits without an accepted answer, much less with an answer that I think most appropriately fits the situation. The purpose of the form that the OP stated is to simply send an email based on input from an HTML form, providing success/failure messages as appropriate. This is not an appropriate situation for an ASP.NET HTTP handler. There is no benefit, that I am aware of, that a HTTP handler will give you over simply POST'ing back to the web form. However, using a postback handler in the web form will allow you to easily do things like:

1. Redirect upon success
2. Display a message upon success
3. Display a message, with details, upon error
4. Redirect, without details, upon error

For example, you could have an ASP.NET Panel control that is ordinarily not visible, but when you encounter an error validating the form or sending the email, you could display the error messages there. If you try to do this with an HTTP handler, you either have to do too much heavy lifting injecting the error message into the same or another page or you have a very bland, text-only message to send to the client.

If you **MUST** use a HTTP handler, I would advise to use Karl Anderson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18768646/2097661) with the addition of setting **at least** `context.Response.StatusCode` to a HTTP status code that makes sense for the error. As the answer stands, if an exception is thrown by the `SendEmail()` method the HTTP handler will send the error message back to the client as HTTP 200 (OK), which is incorrect if there was an exception and the email could not be sent. I have not tested this method (using `context.Response.Write()`), but I do believe that you would just end up with very basic text output to the browser as the response to the POST request resulting from submitting the form. There wouldn't be any HTML, depending on how your application is configured to handle HTTP errors. If you had a custom error handler for HTTP 500, and you configured the `catch` block to set the `StatusCode` to 500, you'd have to configure that custom handler page to read response message in order to inject that message into your custom handler page content.